# Python import file with dependencies in the same folder

Tags: python

I have a file ref.py that depends on a text file `ex.txt`, that is in the same directory `\home\ref_dir` . So it works normally when I run the file `ref.py`, but if I try to import `ref.py` to another file work.py in a different directory `\home\work_dir` , I do the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\home\ref_dir')
import ref
```

But then I get an error, that the program cannot find `ex.txt`

How can I solve this issue without using absolute paths. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what python resources are for. You can import text together with your script/binary and open it as a resource inside your code, not just a file on real filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the os module to get access to the current absolute path of the module that you're in, and then get the dirname from that

You would want to open ex.txt in your file like this.

```
import os

with open('%s/ex.txt' % os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) as ex:
    print ex.read()
```

Comment: for some reason I get this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    os.path.abspath(__file__)
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: Of course you would, what file would you consider "shell" to be? :-P Save your changes to a file, and run that file from python. So instead of python, and then typing __file__ in the interpretor, do "python filename.py", and the __file__ will have something to actually reference :)

Comment: `__file__` is usually how I do this sort of thing too. FWIW if you want to distribute just `.pyc` files I think this will break (`__file__` is basically a constant generated when the `pyc` file is), not sure why you'd want to do that though!

Comment: Also from file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\python_libs\arabic_lib.py", line 37, in <module>
    path='%s/ex.txt' % os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: I think ____file____ for some reason doesn't work, what I need is basically something that can tell me the physical file location from which I am doing the import